# What is the logic to print the below mentioned number pattern

Tags: java, numbers, logic

```
class Num {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++) {
                if(j==1) {
                    System.out.print(i);
                }
                else if(j==2) {
                    System.out.print(" "+(i+j+2));
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(" "+(i+j+4));
                }
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2 6
3 7 10 
4 8 11 12
5 9 12 13 14
```

Expected:

```
1
2 6
3 7 10 
4 8 11 13
5 9 12 14 15
```

I tried so much and came up with this logic

```
when j=1 then i
when j=2 then i+j+2
when j=3 then i+j+4
when j>=4 then i+j+5
```

there are totally 4 conditions here, how do i get do this in nested for loop. Any other logic is also appreciable.

Comment: The logic seems to be that it writes columns of numbers in ascending order, each column having one less number than the previous one. Why not fill a 2D array of numbers, filling the blanks with 0, and then print this 2D array row by row, replacing 0 with white space?

Comment: I don't wanna use arrays. How can i do this with nested for loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int lineCount = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= lineCount; i++) {
    int value = i;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(value +  " ");
        value += lineCount -j;
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot your j = 3 case

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if (j == 1) {
                    System.out.print(" " + i);
                } else if (j == 2) {
                    System.out.print(" " + (i + j + 2));
                } 
                else if(j == 3){
                    System.out.print(" " + (i + j + 4));
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(" " + (i + j + 5));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise and believe that it would be better that our codes be dynamic, meaning it would work on any input of user.Suppose if the question was to change from 5 rows to 6 rows,you have to change the for constructs as well add an additional if construct.
Secondly it would not be a better idea to keep as many if constructs w.r.t the columns you need.

```
  Take the no. of rows the user wants to a variable say 'noofrows'. Then its just the same as your code with little changes:
        int noofrows;
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nGive the no. of rows needed:\n");
    noofrows=(int)s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Number give is:"+noofrows);
    int emptyspaces;
     for(int i = 1; i <= noofrows; i++) 
        {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) 
        {
            emptyspaces=(j)*(j-1)/2;   //counting the no. of emptspace which is an arithmetic progression 
        System.out.print(((j-1)*noofrows+i)-emptyspaces +" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
       s.close();  //edited version
```

Please let me know incase anything went wrong

Comment: Even i want to make the code dynamic, the code you have mentioned does not work. It starts to print from 6

Answer (score 0):

I am not a java developer, so sending you solution in C#. You will have to replace "using System;" with some import statement and Console.WriteLine statements with appropriate System.out.print or println.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        PrintNumbers(1, 5); 
    }

    static void PrintNumbers(int level, int MaxLevel)
    {
        if( MaxLevel < level )
        {
            return;
        }

        int num = 0;
        for(int i = 0, diff=MaxLevel; i < level; i++)
        {
          num += (i == 0)?level:(diff-i);
          Console.Write("{0} ",num);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
        PrintNumbers(level+1, MaxLevel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not post solutions in some other language when the post is tagged with `Java`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n=5;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(j==1)
                cout<<i<<" ";
            else
                cout<<i+j+j<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

/*OUTPUT :-

1 
2 6 
3 7 9 
4 8 10 12 
5 9 11 13 15 

*/
```